# Not able to get the push notification data when the app is killed or when the app is not running

Tags: react-native, push-notification, aws-amplify

I am using react-native with aws-amplify .I am not able to get the push notification data when the app is killed or when the app is not running.I am getting the push notification data, when the app is in background or foreground.

```
componentDidMount() {

   PushNotification.onNotification((notification) => {

   console.log('in app notification', notification);

   notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
 });

// get the registration token
  PushNotification.onRegister((token) => {
    console.log('in app registration', token);
  });

  // get the notification data when notification is opened
  PushNotification.onNotificationOpened((notification) => {
      console.log('the notification is opened', notification);
   });
 }
```

Comment: Use headless Js for getting push notification when app is killed. For more info facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android

Comment: @PradnyaChoudhari I am getting the notification when the app is not in the background or killed but my problem is that i am not able to get the push notification data(i.e title and body),when i click on the push notification.

Comment: @M.K were you able to sort out the issue? I am also having same issue.

Comment: @M.K did anyone make it work? I am also getting the notification when the app is not in the background or killed but my problem is that i am not able to get the push notification data(i.e title and body),when i click on the push notification